# Angularjs ng-disabled is disabling all of my buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that is called on a click. Once it has been clicked, I want to disable the button that was clicked. So far all I was able to do was to get ALL buttons to disable when I click just one. I tried out putting `keys` but I had no luck with that.

Here is my html:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="parcel in parcels">
    <td><a ng-href="http://www.local.com/orders/{{ parcel.id }}/edit/">{{ parcel.id }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ parcel.tid }}</td>
    <td>{{ parcel.srfn }}</td> 
    <td><a  class="btn btn-success"  ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="resolve({{parcel.id}})">Resolve</a></td>                                  
 </tr>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 $scope.isDisabled = false;

 $scope.resolve = function(id)
   {
    $scope.order_id = id;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/outboundsummary/' + $scope.order_id, 
    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.dp);
        $window.alert("Resolved!");
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
        return false;

    });
 }
```

Comment: what is `p` in your html conext, is it perhaps `parcel`?

Comment: p is parcels. I'll change it back so that no one is confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.isDisabled` preserves a single state of a `$scope` variable in your controller. Since you want to disable the state of the resolve button of each parcel in your `ng-repeat`, you can  use the parcel object to dictate its state, additionally you can pass the parcel variable in your `resolve()` function to get both the state and the id. There is no need to interpolate `{{}}` the parcel id when passing angular expressions to `ng-click` callbacks.

**[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/EbyPEZEideOgsJjSx9RR?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$scope.resolve = function(parcel)  {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/outboundsummary/' + parcel.id, 
    })
    .success(function(data){
      parcel.disabled = true;
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="parcel in parcels">
  <td><a ng-href="http://www.local.com/orders/{{ parcel.id }}/edit/">{{ parcel.id }}</a></td>
  <td>{{parcel.id}}</td>
  <td>{{parcel.desc}}</td>
  <td>
    <a class="btn bnt-success" ng-disabled="parcel.disabled" ng-click="resolve(parcel)">Resolve</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

UPDATE:
As discussed in our chat discussion, you're `ng-click` callback should have passed `parcel` instead of `parcel.id` - `ng-click="resolve(parcel)"`

Furthermore, your `resolve()` function should look like this:

```
$scope.resolve = function(parcel) { 
  $http({ 
    method: 'GET', 
    url: '/outboundsummary/' + parace.id, 
  }) 
  .success(function(data){ 
    parcel.disabled = true; 
  }); 
};
```

Comment: I was very hopeful for this fix, but I have no clue why it didn't work. Nothing is disabling. I'm able to keep on clicking the button after clicking it once.

Comment: can you create a plunker? or jsfiddle? its easier look for the problem if you make one.

Comment: when i do a `ng-disabled="parcel.disabled"` would it matter if i change it to `ng-disabled="{{parcel.disabled}}`?

Comment: yes it will, because interpolated values inside an angular expression are evaluated only once

Comment: What I'm getting is that `parcel` is not defined when I write it into the controller. I'm quite confused why we created something called `parcel.disabled`

Comment: `parcel.disabled` is simply a value that we created on the fly when repeating each item in the `ng-repeat` which is only given a value when the `resolve()` is invoked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58760/discussion-between-ryeballar-and-sfas).

Answer (score 1):

Since ng-repeat creates a new child scope for each element this one is easy i think. Try

`<td><a  class="btn btn-success"  ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="[resolve(parcel.id), disabled=true]">Resolve</a></td>`

Comment: Hmm. I'll give this one a try. In my success, I have to somehow turn the 'disabled' to false?

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea, since the `resolve()` function will be invoking an `$http` request, and only when the request was successful will the button be disabled. what if the request fails? Additionally, you could have simply done it this way: `ng-click="resolve(parcel.id); disabled = true"`

Comment: Well i agree, i though this was one time disable only.

Comment: Re-enabling becomes a challenge too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<a ng-disabled="isDisabled(parcel.id)" ng-click="resolve(parcel.id)">Resolve</a>
```

and in your controller:

```
var disabled = [];

$scope.isDisabled = function(id)
{
    if(disabled[id] === undefined) return false;

    return disabled[id];
}

$scope.resolve = function(id)
{
    disabled[id] = true;
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try add

```
{{parcels |json}}
```

above or bellow table to see if problem is in ng-disable or in data you are sending to ng-repeat